# Chef 11 node attributes available and ordering

Tags: ruby, chef, configuration-management

In Chef 10 I have a number of roles which set custom node attributes like

```
"appname": "my_rails_app"
```

The attribute is then used to load app specific variables in a wrapper cookbook. There are different variables and number of variables for each Rails app for example.

```
app = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load('deploy', node.appname)
```

In Chef 11 my run fails because 'node.appname' isn't set until after a successful Chef run. This means server creation has become a 2 step process - launch with base role then bootstrap wrapper cookbook.

I understand why this behavior was changed but I'm curious how to work around it without rewriting my cookbooks and still adhere to DRY.

*UPDATE*

Thanks this is interesting but I'm not sure this works. For example, the generic deploy cookbook which also depends on appname is included in the my_rails_app recipe. So a run looks like

Role - where attribute is set

```
"appname": "my_rails_app"
```

App wrapper cookbook - load variables

```
include_recipe "deploy"
app = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load('deploy', node.appname)
```

Deploy cookbook - load SSH keys

```
app = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load('deploy', node.appname)
```

The deploy cookbook is what kills the Chef run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default attributes already defined in a cookbooks attribute files can be resolved again during a chef client run with `node.from_file`:

```ruby
# set the attribute
node.set[:appname] = "my_rails_app"

# optionally reload node so attribute is available during this chef-client run
node.from_file( run_context.resolve_attribute('your-railapp-cookbook', 'default') )

# and log it. 
Chef::Log.info( "appname [#{node[:appname]}]" )
```

This is a section yanked from [my answers about using attributes](https://serverfault.com/a/531833/125521):

If you are doing this, you may need to think about [saving the node](http://rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Node#save-instance_method) back to the server if this is an important enough checkpoint in your process to warrant extra calls back to the chef server.

Comment: see UPDATE above.

Comment: So the same error is thrown when you use that code? You might need a default attribute defined in the cookbook you are reloading for chef to load the node override. `default[:appname] = 'default'` or whatever suits your code. I never got into the gory detail of what the reload does because it just worked for me, but I tend to define everything in the attribute files.